# How to filter out bad values in a data set regarding a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter

I wanted to ask any keen users here how to "filter out" bad values regarding a tremendous amount of a data matrix in matlab.

e.g: I have a MATLAB data file containing values 2*5000 (double) which represent x and y coordinates. How is it possible to delete all values above or under a certain limit?

or easier:

(matrix from data file)

1 2 4 134 2
3 5 5 4   2

or

1 2 4 9   2
3 5 5 234 2

setting a certain limit and delete column:

1 2 4 2
3 5 5 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find the "bad" elements, e.g. `A < 0 | A > 20`
2. Find the "good" columns, e.g. `~max(A < 0 | A > 20)`
3. Keep the "good" columns / Remove the "bad" columns, e.g. `A(:, ~max(A < 0 | A > 20))`

Comment: I tried this approach by using your method:                                                                       
M = [1 2 4 134 2 : 3 5 5 4 2];
M < 0 | M > 20;
~max(M < 0 | M > 20);
M_FILTER = M(:, ~max(M < 0 | M > 20));                                         
                                                                                                          However I am getting an an empty value for this one. Could you explain this code a little more please? I am still learning matlab.

Comment: @GretaStein Your input `M = [1 2 4 134 2 : 3 5 5 4 2];` is wrong. That's a 1x10 vector, not a 2x5 matrix. This algorithm doesn't work with vectors. What exactly is unclear? That's the basic Matlab operators and functions.

Comment: @GretaStein [or](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html), [lt](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lt.html), [gt](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gt.html), [max](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html), [not](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html), [indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html)